# PHP: Date range selection automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, date-range

I have 3 input fields all together.

1. *Contract period:* 1 years(for example)
2. *start date :* 30 - 1- 2012 (for example)
3. *end date :* ????

(Can we get the end date automatically according to the contract period mentioned, which mean if the date after 1 year is 30-1-2013 can we get it automatically in the third field after mentioning the first and second field).

Comment: Must this be JS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, using `onSelect`  option of jQuery datepicker.

1) get the value of contract year and parse it as `integer`.

```
var addYears = parseInt($('#contract').val(), 10);
```

2) Split the selected date in `startDate`, as below

```
var t = date.split('/');
```

3) Now add the years and [parse it as Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20162708/1671639).

```
var fin = new Date(parseInt(t[2], 10) + addYears, --t[0], t[1]);
```

Finally,

**HTML:**

```
In years only:
<input id="contract" type="text" />
<input id="start" type="text" />
<input id="end" type="text" />
```

**JS:**

```
$('#end').datepicker();
$('#start').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date, args) {
        var addYears = parseInt($('#contract').val());
        var t = date.split('/');
        var fin = new Date(parseInt(t[2], 10) + addYears, --t[0], t[1]);
        $('#end').datepicker("setDate", fin);
    }
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJ93d/2/)

Comment: @praveen... thanks for your effort bro...!! but the end date is picking the same date as the start date!!

Comment: @bzbz I have spotted the wrong fiddle link , check this http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/LJ93d/4/  Let me know if it works ;)

Comment: @praveen.. It works absolutely fine ...thanks for ya help.. cheers bro..!!