# Javascript compare two dates to get a difference

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, compare

I am trying to compare two different dates to see if the date inputted is after 7 days of todays date. I have done a bit of googling and come up with this:

```
function val_date(input){
    var date = new Date(input);
    date = date.getTime() / 1000;
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    window.alert("Date: "+date + " = N_Date: "+timestamp);
    if(timestamp > date || timestamp === date){
        // The selected time is less than 7 days from now
        return false;
    }
    else if(timestamp < date){
    // The selected time is more than 7 days from now
        return true;
    }
    else{
    // -Exact- same timestamps.
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using an alert so that I can check my progress to make sure the dates are different. The output of the alert just says:

> Date: NaN = N_Date = 13255772630 (<- or something like that).

Is there something I am doing wrong here?
Not sure if it helps but my date format is **DD-MM-YYYY**

Comment: *"...the alert just says: Date: NaN"* This tells you that `input`, whatever it is, is a string that cannot be parsed by the `Date` constructor. The result of calling `new Date("some invalid string")` is a `Date` whose time number is `NaN`.

Comment: what is value of input ?

Comment: What is your date format?

Comment: my date format is DD-MM-YYYY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are comparing dates and don't want to include time, you can use something like:

```
// dateString is format DD-MM-YYYY
function isMoreThan7DaysHence(dateString) {

    // Turn string into a date object at 00:00:00
    var t = dateString.split('-');
    var d0 = new Date(t[2], --t[1], t[0]);

    // Create a date for 7 days hence at 00:00:00
    var d1 = new Date();
    d1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    d1.setDate(d1.getDate() + 7);

    return d0 >= d1;
}
```

Note that the hours for today's date must be zeroed.

Comment: +1 Perfectly noticed, the best part in yours I like is `--t[1]`.

Comment: And some want strict typing in ECMAScript… ;-)

Comment: That solved the problem, converting the string into a valid date was definitely the right way to go.  Smart Move

Answer (score 3):

Date: `NaN` Because string which you are passing to date creation is not possible to create Date

---

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/SwCU4/)</kbd>

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
    this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
    return this;
};

function val_date(input) {
    var inputDate = new Date(input);
    var dateWeek = new Date().addDays(7);
    console.log(inputDate, dateWeek);
    if (inputDate < dateWeek) {
        // The selected time is less than 7 days from now
        return false;
    } else {
        // The selected time is more than 7 days from now
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP's string format is DD-MM-YYYY which will not be correctly parsed by most browser Date constructors. Date strings should be manually parsed. The created date will be at 0:00:00 but *dateWeek* will be at the current time so will return false on the 7th day when it should return true.

Answer (score 0):

Using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
moment([2013, 2, 29]).fromNow();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common and if you will be manipulating dates you might want to use a Javascript library for this.  There is an excellent on called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Using this you would do something like:

`moment().add('days', 7)`

To find a week in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that input is a valid Javascript Date object, you could perhaps try:

```
function dateDifference(oldDate) {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var difference = currentDate - oldDate; //unit: milliseconds
    var numDays = 7;
    var threshHoldTime = numDays * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); //seven days in milliseconds
    if (difference > threshHoldTime ) {
        console.log("The difference is greateer then then 7 days");
    }
    else {
        console.log("the date is not enough: " + difference);
    }
}
```

Comment: *input* is a string, not a date object.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var date = new Date(input).getTime(); // Get the milliseconds
var today = new Date();    

//You can't compare date, 
//so convert them to milliseconds
today = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 7)).getTime(); 
if (inputDate < today) {
    // The selected time is less than 7 days from now
    return false;
 } else if{ ()
    // -Exact- same timestamps.
    return false;
 }
 else {
    // The selected time is more than 7 days from now
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: *input* is a string that will not be correctly parsed by the Date constructor (as noted in the OP). Date objects **can** be directly compared.

Comment: @RobG comparing date objects didn't worked check this http://jsfiddle.net/g9KGR/  Corrct me if meant wrong

Comment: @RobG `var date = new Date("12-12-2013");` is working only in chrome but fails in other browsers.  I missed to note this before, so I posted the answer.

Comment: Ok, you can't use the `==` operator because it uses the [abstract equality algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), but you can use operators like `>` and `<` because they use the [abstract relational comparison](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) that coerces the operands to number first.

Comment: @RobG  Thank you, for taking your time for this explanation.  Still lot to learn :)