# How to compare the date part alone from a date time value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables namely

```
date1 = Mon Nov 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
date2 = Mon Nov 25 2013 14:13:55 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

When I compare the two dates I get that `date2` is greater which I need is correct. But I do not want to check the time part of the two dates I have. How could I get the date part alone from these two dates and compare it?

```
var today = new Date();     //Mon Nov 25 2013 14:13:55 GMT+0530 (IST) 
d = new Date(my_value);     //Mon Nov 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST) 
if(d>=today){               //I need to check the date parts alone.
    alert(d is greater than or equal to current date);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing date part only without comparing time in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698725/comparing-date-part-only-without-comparing-time-in-javascript)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Try clearing the time using [`Date.setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

```js
dateObj.setHours(hoursValue[, minutesValue[, secondsValue[, msValue]]])
```

**Example Code**:

```js
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
d = new Date(my_value); 
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

if(d >= today){ 
    alert(d is greater than or equal to current date);
}
```

Comment: @Outlooker *FYI* [you can't use == for date comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162435/javascript-compare-two-dates-to-get-a-difference/20162708#comment30055600_20162603).  Just to let you know.

Comment: is right.  Try comparing like this `d.getTime()==today.getTime()`

Answer (score 13):

The best way would be to modify the accepted answer's `if` statement as follows

```
if(d.setHours(0,0,0,0) >= today.setHours(0,0,0,0))
```

In this way, you can easily check for equality as well because the return type for `setHours()` is integer.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
var today = new Date();     // Mon Nov 25 2013 14:13:55 GMT+0530 (IST)
var d = new Date(my_value); // Mon Nov 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

// This will write a Date with time set to 00:00:00 so you kind of have date only
var todayDateOnly = new Date(
    today.getFullYear(),
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDate());

var dDateOnly = new Date(
    d.getFullYear(),
    d.getMonth(),
    d.getDate());

if (dDateOnly >= todayDateOnly) {
    alert("d is greater than or equal to current date");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
     var StartDate = $("#StartDate").val();

      var EndDate = $("#EndDate").val();

      if ((( EndDate - StartDate)/ (86400000*7))<0) 
      { 
       alert("Start Date Must Be Earlier Than End Date"); $("#StartDate").focus(); 
        error = true; 
        return false; 
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please realize this question is more than 2 years old… You can still answer of course, especially when techniques evolve, new tools / languages are available, which open room for better solutions. In that case, please kindly explain why you think your solution is better than the previously proposed ones.