# Days Since Last Login using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate DaysSinceLastLogin, and want to use the below functionality(Found on google):

```
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const firstDate = new Date(2008, 1, 12);
const secondDate = new Date(2008, 1, 22);
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate - secondDate) / oneDay));
```

So with my scenario, My `firstdate` format is in string: `"2020-03-06 18:20:36:187"` 
and the `secondDate` would be today's date so basically I need the `firstDate` and `secondDate` to be passed in the above function but format is different, how can I convert `firstdate` and today's date in the required format?

Comment: Use https://momentjs.com/

Comment: i would recommend you to try moment framework in JS

Answer (score 1):

The [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor accepts a date string as the first parameter. If the constructor is used without any parameters it will be initialised with the current date.

```
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
const lastLoginDate = new Date("2020-03-06 18:20:36:187");
const todaysDate = new Date(); // Current date
const diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((lastLoginDate - todaysDate) / oneDay));
```

I would however recommend using a library such as [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to handle DateTime manipulation in javascript since even the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) recommends against using the DateTime Object for string conversion:

> Note: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and
>   Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to
>   browser differences and inconsistencies.

Alternatively you could handle DateTime manipulation on the server side (with PHP for example) to ensure a consistent user experience

Finally I will also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript) which goes into more details about parsing Date strings in JS and is perhaps what you should have searched for originally rather than creating a new question.

Comment: If `new Date()` is not sufficient because it returns the hours, minutes, seconds..., then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445377/how-to-get-current-date-without-time) can help. Just do `todaysDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)` and it set any time to 0, giving the pure date.

Comment: @Liam I decided to post the solution first while I was writing up the explanation incase the OP was after a quick response. I have now updated my answer.