compare two date with each other with the same value of year and month and day but diffrent hours
I am about the compare two dates in JavaScript with each other
for example consider this two value :
date1 = 2024-5-13T20:30:00
date2 = 2024-5-13T21:30:20

the day and month is the same but the hours is different
my goal is to return true for each day that have the same value as month and year and ...
its should compare the date in the format yyyy/mm/dd
the method I used first time :
date1.toISOString().split('T')[0] === date2.toISOString().split('T')[0]

this method is not suitable for me because its loop between the characters of time string then split and its reduce the performance

You said the answer in your question. Format it to yyyy/mm/dd and check if these two string are the same.

you can also use getDate(), getMonth(), getFullYear() on each date object and check if they match https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

You can also simple remove the time() part:  see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25445633/2181514

If your concern is performance, then consider make the comparison at source instead of in javascript.

do you want to compare UTC or local timezone? because they could be different

Cut time in UTC:


const date1 = new Date('2024-05-13T23:30:00'), date2 = new Date('2024-05-14T00:30:20');

const DAY_TIME = 3600 * 24 * 1000;
const isSameDate =  (a, b) => (a = a.getTime(), b = b.getTime(), (a - a % DAY_TIME) === (b - b % DAY_TIME));
console.log(date1.toLocaleString(), '-', date2.toLocaleString());
console.log(isSameDate(date1, date2));



Cut time in local timezone:


const date1 = new Date('2024-05-13T23:30:00'), date2 = new Date('2024-05-14T00:30:20');

const DAY_TIME = 3600 * 24 * 1000;
const offset = date1.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
const isSameDate =  (a, b) => (a = a.getTime() - offset, b = b.getTime() - offset, (a - a % DAY_TIME) === (b - b % DAY_TIME));
console.log(date1.toLocaleString(), '-', date2.toLocaleString());
console.log(isSameDate(date1, date2));



Let's benchmark:
` Chrome/124
----------------------------------------------------------
cut time         ■ 1.00x | x1000000000 335 337 342 347 363
Wimanicesir     3373.13x |     x100000 113 116 119 123 146
DateTimeFormat  3820.90x |     x100000 128 128 132 136 141
---------------------------------------------------------- `

Open in the playground


const date1 = new Date('2024-05-13T20:30:00'), date2 = new Date('2024-05-13T21:30:20');

// @benchmark Wimanicesir
const isSameDate0 = (a, b) => a.toLocaleDateString() === b.toLocaleDateString();
// @run
isSameDate0(date1, date2);

// @benchmark DateTimeFormat
const {format} = Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US');
const isSameDate1 = (a, b) => format(a) === format(b);
// @run
isSameDate1(date1, date2);

// @benchmark cut time
const DAY_TIME = 3600 * 24 * 1000;
const isSameDate2 = (a, b) => (a = a.getTime(), b = b.getTime(), (a - a % DAY_TIME) === (b - b % DAY_TIME));
// @run
isSameDate2(date1, date2);

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Why not use toLocaleDateString?

@Wimanicesir  The poster has explicitly used UTC in this question.

Don't know why this is a problem. I made an answer to show this.

Just to be complete, could you also benchmark with new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date) and compare these two?

There is a mix of locale & UTC times here, if the OP wants UTC, only your cut time is correct, if you want it all UTC you can use the getUTCMonth methods etc.

@Wimanicesir it formats m/d/y which isn't comparable.

@Keith agree...

@AlexanderNenashev, it is comparable! However, it is just as slow (maybe even slower), so cut time it is!

@Wimanicesir a year should be compared first...

If the two strings are the same, they are the same. Year could even be in the middle. You are right if you want to know the biggest date though.

@Wimanicesir added, not faster

Thanks! The documentation explicitly says this is faster than tolocaledatecompare, guess they are wrong though! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

@Wimanicesir  It is faster on Firefox, but looks like Chrome it's slower.  In either case the difference is marginal.  To be fair to MDN it says -> which is potentially inefficient, Looks like browsers have this optimised pretty well.

Using toLocaleDateString is a short way to check this, however Intl.DateTimeFormat is faster:


const date1 = new Date('2024-05-13T20:30:00'), date2 = new Date('2024-05-13T21:30:20');

const isSameDate = (a, b) => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(a) === new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(b);

console.log(isSameDate(date1, date2));




Did you not see the toISOString in the OP's question?  This could give different results depending on the time,.  It might be the OP wants locale time, but might be best checking first.

I saw it but why does it matter only in my solution? If the original input does not show the correct day (because of the timezone), other solutions will not work as well.. What is your suggestion?

No other solutions will work fine, the cut time is UTC based, and you have things like .getUTCMonth that will work for UTC.

Dates in JS land can sometimes be tricky!!, and your toLocaleDateString would be ideal for locale time comparing.  But I thought it might be a good idea to give you an example of were the problem lies.   Here in the UK were in what's called BST(British Summer Time).  So an ISO date like new Date('2024-05-13T23:30:00Z') formatted with toLocaleDateString(), will give you the 14th, and not the 13th.

var date1 = 2024-5-13T20:30:00
var date2 = 2024-5-13T21:30:20

var tempdate1 = new Date(date1);
var tempdate2 = new Date(date2);

// Extract the date parts
var year1 = tempdate1 .getFullYear();
var month1 = tempdate1 .getMonth() + 1;
var day1 = tempdate1 .getDate();

var year2 = tempdate2 .getFullYear();
var month2 = tempdate2 .getMonth() + 1;
var day2 = tempdate2 .getDate();

if(year1 === year2 && month1 === month2 && day1 === day2){

}

Try this code. If you have any problem further, feel free to reach out me.

Your code has syntax errors. Also this solution is already given.

You can create a snippet that includes your code, especially if it's entirely javascript.  Then we can see it in action (and you can run it before posting to ensure there's no errors).  See  the [<>] button during edit.
