# Remove time from json feed

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `json` feed with date and time in this format published `2016-09-26T02:18:40.000Z` and I want to remove the time `T02:18:40.000Z` from showing.

this is the code

```
var feedUrl = 'var feedUrl = 'http://www.myfeed.com'

GetFeed(feedUrl , BuildCreative ); //get feeds with feed parser url and callback function


//callback for feedGetter
function BuildCreative(data){
    console.log(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){

        var split_date = 



        document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='feed-content'><a href="+ data[i].link +" target='_blank'><div id='imgHolder'><img src='" + data[i].image.replace('w=98' , 'w=140') + "'></img></div><p>"+ data[i].title  +"</p></a><span class='feed-date'>"+ data[i].published + "</span></div>";
    }
}

//Get feeds function partly based on jquery
function GetFeed(url , callback ){var request = new XMLHttpRequest();request.open('GET', url, true);request.onload = function() {if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);callback(data);} else {console.log('error getting feeds');}};request.onerror = function(e) {console.log(e);};request.send();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the result I wanted by using slice

```
document.body.innerHTML += "<div class='feed-content'><a href="+data[i].link +" target='_blank'><div id='imgHolder'><img src='" + data[i].image.replace('w=98' , 'w=140') + "'></img></div><p>"+ data[i].title  +"</p></a><span class='feed-date'>"+ data[i].published.slice('0' , '10')  + "</span></div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Date` object from your string and then format it's output rather easily.

```
var date = new Date("2016-09-26T02:18:40.000Z");

var dateString = [
  date.getUTCFullYear() , 
  ("0" + (date.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2), 
  ("0" + date.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)
].join("-");
```

Comment: Thanks you gave me the idea of using slice.

Comment: @JosephZammit Your date string contains a timezone value, directly splicing it in half can result horribly in different browsers having different timezones.

Comment: Ok noted i'll see how i go with this first

Comment: if you take this approach and construct a Date object, you can use `.toDateString()` to output a readable date value, compatible with any locale https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString - highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `moment.js` try this

```
.startOf('day')
```

For more information see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130735/how-can-i-remove-time-from-my-date-with-moment-js) and [this documantation page](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/)

If you use pure js look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188317/how-to-compare-the-date-part-alone-from-a-date-time-value) The main idea is get date and set seconds, hours and other to zero:

```
d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```