# How do I parse an ISO date string in d3.js v4?

Tags: d3.js

Given a string `"2001-01-30"`, how can I parse it and obtain a JavaScript Date object, ideally using d3.js v4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted date string, use the d3.js v4 method [`d3.isoParse`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format/blob/master/README.md#isoParse).

For example, in my location (Calgary, Alberta):

```
d3.isoParse("2001-01-30");
```

returns:

```
Mon Jan 29 2001 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

To return a [consistent end-of-day value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188317), clear the time using `Date.setHours(hour,min,sec,millisec)`:

```
let d = d3.isoParse("2001-01-30)
          .setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(d);
```

Returns:

```
Mon Jan 29 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```