# How to convert the string (01/02/2013 22:13) to date in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two strings:

```
var string1 = "01/02/2013 22:13";
var string2 = "08/01/2013 02:01";
```

I want convert to date in JavaScript to compare 2 dates.

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8224508/2970947).

Comment: be careful about globalization.  cultures (and thus users' browsers) vary between whether they expect M/D/Y or D/M/Y.  your best bet is to pass the strings into javascript in a standard format that removes that ambiguity (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't prefer `Date` object to be used to *parse your date string.*  Instead do it yourself like this.

Here below I have written a method to parse your string to Date

```
function convertToDate(datSt) {
        var s1 = datSt.split(" ");
        var s1dat = s1[0].split("/");
        var s1Tim = s1[1].split(":");
        return new Date(s1dat[2], s1dat[1], s1dat[0], s1Tim[0], s1Tim[1])
    }
```

Using **`Date.getTime()`** which returns you the millisecond, so that you can perform your Date comparison very easily.

```
    if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
        //do whatever
    } else if (d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()) {
        //do whatever
    } else {
        //do whatever
    }
```

Finally,

```
var string1 = "01/02/2013 22:13";
var string2 = "08/01/2013 02:01";

var d1 = convertToDate(string1);
var d2 = convertToDate(string2);

//getTime returns milliseconds, which can used for comparison
if (d1.getTime() > d2.getTime()) {
    //do whatever
} else if (d1.getTime() < d2.getTime()) {
    //do whatever
} else {
    //do whatever
}

// Below is the method to split your string to Date object
function convertToDate(datSt) {
    var s1 = datSt.split(" ");
    var s1dat = s1[0].split("/");
    var s1Tim = s1[1].split(":");
    return new Date(s1dat[2], s1dat[1], s1dat[0], s1Tim[0], s1Tim[1])
}
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHKcU/)

**FYI:**  You can't perform equity(`==`) operation with Date objects.  others(`>` and `<`) can be performed, follow this [**comment**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162435/javascript-compare-two-dates-to-get-a-difference/20162603#comment30055600_20162603) to know the reason.

If you wish to use plugin, I would prefer [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) for a simple parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing date strings in JS is hard.  First you need to know what format the string represents - the ones you posted are ambiguous.  Libraries like http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/ can help with various unambiguous forms.  Definitely use a library because this stuff is tricky and browser's are inconsistent in how they implement 'standard' functions like Date.parse

Answer (score -1):

```
var date1 = new Date(string1); //Turn it into a date
var date2 = new Date(string2); //Turn the other thing into a date
console.log(Math.abs(date1 - date2)); //Take the absolute value of the subtraction
```

As @RobertLevy points out, this might not work depending on the culture of the user. (D/M/Y vs M/D/Y), so it is preferred that you deal with all dates server-side, so the browser only gets the (correct) timestamp.

Comment: this makes assumptions about culture D/M/Y vs M/D/Y (the assumption being that the code doesn't care and can do whatever the user's culture dictates which almost certainly be incorrect)

Comment: also, please explain your codes.

Comment: @RobertLevy, Shivan Edited. Is there any way around the cultural problem?

Comment: @Dude to the solution is that anytime you provide date strings to JS, (via a server or otherwise) it needs to be in an unambiguous format such as an ISO 8601 string